# Secure Web-Services with WS-Trust/SAML using PicketLink in JBoss 7?

Tags: jboss7.x, saml, ws-trust

I have a Web-Service that's being called from a remote Java program. I want to secure the Web Service with WS-Trust, using PicketLink. PicketLink is working, and I can obtain a token (assertion) from the picketlink-sts, using the WSTrustClient class.

But in JBoss 7, there appears to be no way to supply any of the client-side WS runtime classes with this token. The samples on the JBoss sites use this:

```
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(SAML2Constants.SAML2_ASSERTION_PROPERTY, assertion);
```

But org.picketlink.trust.jbossws.SAML2Constants does not exist because there are no org.picketlink.trust packages in any of the JBoss 7 or PicketLink jars.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with PicketLink (yet). But some Googling led me to this [forum question & answer](https://community.jboss.org/thread/160132).

Comment: Thanks for the find. It's about someone looking for the source to the (pre-AS7) trust package.

I found this: https://community.jboss.org/message/722339
"The trust jar contains deeper integration with JBossWS (handlers etc) which we have not finished/tested for AS7.x"

Given the lack of evidence for anything (including samples) of how to secure a remotely accessible web-service with WS-Trust tokens, it looks that this (important) feature still hasn't been implemented yet. Disturbing that noone else is asking for this.

Comment: ... it makes me think that this whole PicketLink is an incomplete improperly supported alternative to this: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/